# WSL2 Hibernate Ubuntu 22 Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd, wsl2

Why are (or how can I stop) my WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 instances shutting down when I hibernate my Windows 10 laptop?

I have been happily using WSL1 for some time and recently got WSL2 working correctly. I have both my WSL1 Ubuntu 20 and WSL2 Ubuntu 22 running, then hibernate the laptop (that is total power off, unlike sleep). On boot, all my open programs are where I left them, including the WSL1 instances, but the WSL2 instances have closed.

My hunch is it is related to me enabling systemd on the WSL2 instance, but that is too useful to turn off (I'd rather live with this annoying feature). I suspect that because of the last entry in `/var/log/syslog` for that day

```
systemd[1]: rsyslog.service: Sent signal SIGHUP to main process 149 (rsyslogd) on client request.
```

There are no other obvious errors about processes failing etc, though I might not have checked all the right logs.

Mainly my google-fu has failed me in understanding what is creating that message and how I can stop it being sent, or prevent it from being actioned by my WSL2 instances.

**I was hoping to find a simple "add this incantation to your systemd.conf"** then my WSL2 wont shutdown when this SIGHUP is sent. Though I would not be surprised to find there is a totally different explanation.

My system info:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz   2.11 GHz  16.0 GB
- WSL2 - Ubuntu 22.04

```
> wsl -v
WSL version: 1.1.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.49
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.2604

$ cat /etc/wsl.conf
[boot]
systemd=true

# Enable extra metadata options by default
[automount]
enabled = true
root = /mnt/
options = "metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002"
mountFsTab = false
```

Comment: Are you saying your WSL1 instances remain running while Windows is in hibernation or are you saying the status of the WSL1 process is properly restored?

Comment: There are many posts about WSL2 not playing nice with hibernate or sleep. The most common symptom is that WSL2 starts consuming CPU and hangs. For example this post with the latest entry dating from today: [WSL is non-responsive after waking from hibernate #8696](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8696). So the problem could be worse... At this time, there doesn't seem to be a workaround for the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound - Hibernate turns your computer off entirely. There are no processes running at all. The WSL1 processes come back where I left them (as you expect with hibernate), the WSL2 processes "seem" to have been told to close by the hibernate process

Comment: @harrymc - I did see a number of nasty looking issues with WSL (1 & 2) but none seemed close to what I am seeing. It genuinely looks like WSL2 is being politely asked to stop, that would be what I would expect to happen if I did a shutdown. I was hoping there might be a linux hack where I can stop the main process getting that SIGHUP

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9695) the problem may perhaps be solved by [disabling fast startup](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10).

Comment: @Martin - Yes; I absolutely know how hibernate works. Trying to understand your description. Windows supports restoration of an application status, to what it was before the system was shutdown.

Comment: @harrymc - I'll try that, it's the middle of my work day before the weekend, so I'll report back Monday if it had any effect.

Comment: I think the setting made things better but our networks team were "playing" on Friday and as we use Cisco Any Connect for our VPN (which behaves oddly with WSL2 at the best of times) that caused both my instances to die when they unplugged us. That of course may have been the issue all along, i.e. when I hibernate the VPN disconnects and that upsets WSL2. I left an instance running and it was still there when I restarted this morning but I don't feel that was a fair test. Will see how it goes over the next few days.

Comment: The setting does not seem to be having any effect. I hibernated on Monday, restarted Wednesday and both the WSL2 instances I had open are gone. I'm going to try dropping the VPN before I hibernate, just to check it isn't related to the network disappearing suddenly

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I have been without this issue for over a week now.

@harrymc made a comment that looks like it could be helping more than I initially reported.

> According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9695) the problem may perhaps be solved by [disabling fast startup](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10)

It also helps that our network team have stopped playing with things for now, so our VPN connections are stable again. Also there's been a windows update. I do not have the time or patience to get to the bottom of what, if any, was the silver bullet.

However I am quite happy with my "just in case" solutions so have kept them anyway.

---

This is even more random than I initially thought. In 1 week, I have had the instances stay running, exit, disappear (crash?), and disappear only when I looked at them (they where on a 2nd desktop and when I slid to it I saw them for a second).

Instead of trying to understand the weirdness of windows, I just decided to work around my main grievances with this behaviour.

Some hacks to my `.bashrc`

1. Losing the history

```
# Write history immediately so it isn't lost if/when the instance dies
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a && history -n'
```

2. Losing the path

```
# Create a new cd function that writes pwd to ~/.lwd each time
function cd()
{
  builtin cd $1
  pwd > ~/.lwd
}

# Start in the last folder we changed into
cd $(cat ~/.lwd)
```

This isn't a great solution because it means that all my instances open in the same place but it's better than nothing and combined with the history storing is good enough. Maybe I might be bothered to get the last cd, then last -1, last -2, etc for each new instance but that'll get complicated.